# Regarding BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

i do the below java print command for this double variable 
double test=58.15;
When i do a System.out.println(test); and System.out.println(new Double(test).toString()); It prints as 58.15.

When i do a System.out.println(new BigDecimal(test)) I get the below value
58.14999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375

I am able to understand "test" double variable value is internally stored as  58.1499999. But when i do the below two System.out.println i am getting the output as 58.15 and not 58.1499999.

System.out.println(test);

System.out.println(new Double(test).toString());

It prints the output as 58.15 for the above two.

Is the above System.out.println statements are doing some rounding of the value 58.1499999 and printing it as 58.15?

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("58.15"));
```

To construct a BigDecimal from a hard-coded constant, you must always use one of constants in the class ([ZERO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO), [ONE](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE), or [TEN](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#TEN)) or one of the string constructors.  The reason is that one you put the value in a double, you've already lost precision that can never be regained.

EDIT: polygenelubricants is right.  Specifically, you're using [Double.toString](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) or equivalent.  To quote from there:

> How many digits must be printed for
>   the fractional part of m or a? There
>   must be at least one digit to
>   represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many,
>   more digits as are needed to uniquely
>   distinguish the argument value from
>   adjacent values of type double. That
>   is, suppose that x is the exact
>   mathematical value represented by the
>   decimal representation produced by
>   this method for a finite nonzero
>   argument d. Then d must be the double
>   value nearest to x; or if two double
>   values are equally close to x, then d
>   must be one of them and the least
>   significant bit of the significand of
>   d must be 0.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `println` (or more precisely, `Double.toString`) rounds. For proof, `System.out.println(.1D);` prints `0.1`, which is impossible to represent in binary.

Also, when using `BigDecimal`, don't use the `double` constructor, because that would attempt to precisely represent an imprecise value. Use the `String` constructor instead.

Comment: I am assuming  new BigDecimal("52.15") or  double test=52.15;
new BigDecimal(new Double(test).toString())  are one and the same. Pls correct me if i am wrong.  My understanding is  new Double( double variable).toString takes the rounded value 58.15 and not 58.149999999.  Does it do any rounding?  So the results are same if i use either way?

Comment: @arav: No they are not the same. The string constructor does not loose precision but the double one already has lost it. That is, the double is already 58.149999 when you call the constructor. Also, it does not do any rounding, it uses the raw bits to construct exactly what you give it.

Comment: Yes, `Double.toString(.1D).equals("0.1")`, and yes, rounding did occur here. `.1D` is not exactly `0.1`, but `Double.toString` rounds to it. This is a "two wrongs make it right" kind of scenario which you should not rely on.

Comment: Opps, yes I misread that comment and mixed up with what you were saying in your answer and then OP. In the OP the issue is that he is using a double directly in the BigDecimal constructor and that is the problem.

Comment: poly, so your saying it will give me the same output if i use new BigDecimal(Double.toString(doublevariable))  instead of  Bigdecimal("52.15").  if its going to give me the same output then it's a workaround right?   In what cases this might fail?

Comment: `Double.toString(1.0000000000000001D).equals("1.0")`, precision is lost due to rounding.

Answer (score 1):

`out.println` and `Double.toString()` use the format specified in [Double.toString(double)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)).

BigDecimal uses more precision by default, as described in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)), and when you call `toString()` it outputs all of the characters up to the precision level available to a primitive double since .15 does not have an exact binary representation.